# VScode Syntax Highlighting Problem from Microsoft C# Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with the VScode code highlighting where the colour of the line under sort of reflects the line above (Some parts of it copies the colours from above). I discovered this while programming in C#, I opened the project and the highlighting was messed up.

I've tried restarting VScode and changing themes to no avail. So that left one possible source of the problems; extensions. Using trial and error, I have pin pointed the cause to the issue of being the Microsoft C# extension.

I need the C# extension to be able to program in C# so I'm not sure of what to do from here.

**C# Extension**

[image: Image of the Microsoft C# Extension]

**Before Enabling the C# Extension**
[image: Before Enabling the extension]

**After Enabling the C# Extension**
[image: After Enabling the extension]

Comment: if you have disabled the C# extension who is syntax highlighting the code, do you have 2 extensions defining a C# TextMate Grammar? Try disable all extensions except C# extension

Answer (score 0):

**The Only Fix I've Found So Far**

I've found that if I uninstall Vscode and reinstall it, the highlighting issue is fixed. Though if you can find a solution that doesn't require uninstallation that would be great.